# Proxying TCP connections?

Tags: sockets, tcp, proxy, websocket

We need to support proxy for companies to use our solution.
The problem is that all data transferred are done via the "raw" TCP protocol.

Is it possible to proxify TCP over enterprise proxies? (I don't think so as there is no any header in packe like HTTP)

We are looking to implement Websocket for data tranfer instead (possible to proxy), is it a good idea?

Thanks

PS: the modules we use are https://github.com/tj/axon and https://github.com/foreverjs/nssocket

Comment: a "socks proxy" should be what you are searching for

Comment: webSocket data can certainly be proxied too (nginx can do that, for example).